# Problem extracting text from RSS feeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, web-crawler

I am new to the world of Ruby and Rails.

I have seen rails cast 190 and I just started playing with it. I used selector gadget to find out the CSS and XPath

I have the following code..

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'nokogiri'  
require 'open-uri'  

url = "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/rss"  
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  
doc.xpath('//a').each do |paragraph|
puts paragraph.text
end
```

When I extracted text from a normal HTML page with css, I could get the extracted text on the console.

But when I try to do the same either with CSS or XPath for the RSS Feed for the following URL mentioned in the code above, I dont get any output.

How do you extract text from RSS feeds??

I also have another silly question.

Is there a way to extract text from 2 different feeds and display it on the console

something like

```
url1 = "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/rss"
url2 = "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/cricket/rss"
```

Looking forward for your help and suggestions

Thank You

Gautam

Comment: I tried using ".to_s" but it still didn't work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rss page is not HTML document, it is XML, so you should use `Nokogiri::XML(open(url))`

Then view source code of the rss page. There are no `<a>` elements.

All links in document are created with the `<link>` tag:

```
<link>http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/world-cup-2010/teams/france/7769203/France-2-Costa-Rica-1-match-report.html</link>
```

Links to each article are also duplicated as `<guid>` tag, because article's ID in RSS is it's URL.

```
<guid>http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/world-cup-2010/teams/france/7769203/France-2-Costa-Rica-1-match-report.html</guid>
```

So, if you need all links in document, use:

```
url = "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/rss"  
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))  
doc.xpath('//link').each do |paragraph|
  puts paragraph.text
end
```

If you need only links to articles, use `doc.xpath('//guid')`

As for the many feeds, just use loop

```
feeds = ["http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/rss", "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/cricket/rss"]
feeds.each do |url|
  #and here goes code as before
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing feeds you should use [Feedzilla](http://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing

http://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra

Works like a charm.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have these installed:
libxml2
libxml2-dev
libxslt
libxslt-dev

Answer (score 0):

No need for the loop... simply

```
puts doc.xpath('//link/text()')
```

will print all link text.